# jQuery get multiple data from custom attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a select element and i wanna take some custom data from this. I don't know if this syntax is right but is possible to get the data??

```
<select data-select="placeholder:This is title; width:300px; dissabled; hidden;"></select>
```

If the attribute have inside colon [ : ] , the left part i wanna use it something like new attribute and the right part as the value of this
The semicolon [ ; ] is used to break this new attributes
The logic is like the style attribute 
The code i wanna have this form:

```
$("[data-selectlist]").each(function(){
    var $ul = $("<ul/>", {
        'placeholder': $(this).attr('placeholder'),
        'width' : $(this).attr('width')
    });
    .
    .
    .
});
```

With what i can replace the .attr() to have the desired result??

Comment: Your *"jQuery to get the data like this"* has nothing to do with your question. Try to be more specific. Show the JS that *actually* gets some data. Describe your desired output. Please read [ask].

Comment: I made some changes. Is better now??

Comment: Now seems definitely better!

Comment: I'm just confused why on earth would you ever want to make a `<ul>` element **hidden, disabled** etc. An `<ul>` cannot be disabled and have `width` attribute :)

Comment: It was just to test non colon attributes. I wanna create a custom select option with full features xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Access every `$("[data-select]")` element `.attr("data-select")`
- iterate the value and create an object like `{attr1:val, attr2:val}`
- Apply the created attributs object to the same (or some) element:
  `$(this).attr(attrObj)` or `$("<ul/>", {attr: attrObj})`

```js
$("[data-select]").attr("data-select", function(i, data) {

  if ( !data ) return; // Early return
  
  // Convert data values to attributes object
  const attrObj = data.match(/(?!\s)[^;]+/g).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const p = cur.split(":");
    acc[p[0]] = p[1] || p[0];
    return acc;
  }, {});

  console.log(attrObj);
  
  // Apply attributs object to element
  $(this).attr(attrObj)

});
```

```html
Select is now hidden! Inspect element to see the attributes applied!<br>
<select data-select="placeholder:This is title;   width:300px; disabled; hidden;">
  <option>test</option>
</select>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```